# Centering UIImage and UILabel together

Tags: uiimage, uilabel, center

I want to center my label's text while also considering a 20x20 image that should always be just to the left of the label. Specifically, I have three labels who's text could be anything, and I want a check mark to always appear just to the left of each label - this position will vary depending on the text length though.

My best guess is making the image a subview of the label and then indenting the text but that still will be somewhat inconsistent...

Comment: Can you use iOS 6 and constraints or only springs and struts?

Comment: @GayleDDS I want iOS 5 compability; I'm not sure what you're asking exactly though..

Comment: in iOS 6 apple added a very flexible constraint system to dynamically position sub-views. But if you need iOS 5 then you can't use it. Your left with the tried and true springs and struts (Autosizing). Is this for a table view or a plain view

Comment: i'm familiar with springs and struts, just not exactly sure how to employ them here. plain view

Comment: Hi @Ryan thanks for quick replies, I need to test my theory on this but will be off line for the next 36 hours. I'll post my findings then. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6 you can do this with constraints and almost no code. But for iOS 5 using only springs and struts you need to manage the view frames your self. You will also need to call `sizeToFit` so the UILabel resizes it's self to the current text.

Here is some example code:

```
- (void)centerLabels
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    NSArray *allLabelsAndChecks = @[ @[self.label1, self.check1], @[self.label2, self.check2], @[self.label3, self.check3] ];

    for (NSArray *labelAndCheck in allLabelsAndChecks) {
        UILabel     *label = labelAndCheck[0];
        UIImageView *check = labelAndCheck[1];

        [label sizeToFit];

        CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
        CGRect checkFrame = check.frame;

        CGFloat maxWidth = viewFrame.size.width - (leftMarginText + rightMargin);

        if (labelFrame.size.width > maxWidth) {
            labelFrame.origin.x   = leftMarginText;
            labelFrame.size.width = maxWidth;
            checkFrame.origin.x = leftMarginImage;
        } else {
            CGFloat slideRight = (maxWidth - labelFrame.size.width) / 2.0;
            labelFrame.origin.x = leftMarginText + slideRight;
            checkFrame.origin.x = leftMarginImage + slideRight;
        }

        label.frame = labelFrame;
        check.frame = checkFrame;
    }
}
```

The commplete demo project can be found here: https://github.com/GayleDDS/TestCenteredLabel.git

[image]

Comment: you're the best mate; had figured it out in the meantime but you're spot on - can't thank you enough!